# How to get repeating groups with regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have this string for instance:

```
Something`3[[typeOne],[typeTwo],[typeThree]][[typeOne],[typeTwo],[typeThree]]
```

Which can contain N types:

```
[[type1],...,[typeN]]
```

I want to extract these internal `typeX` strings (`type1`, ... , `typeN`). I use this pattern (ignore whitespaces - it's just for readability):

```
\[
   (?:,?\[
      ([^\]]*)
   \])+
\]
```

But it gives me only the last type (`typeN`). How can I get all the `typeX` strings using regex?

## Edit:

Actually, the real problem is

```
Something`3[[typeOne],[typeTwo],[typeThree]]
```

Which can contain N types:

```
Something`N[[type1],...,[typeN]]
```

And my regex is:

```
(?:`(?<count>\d+)\[
   (?:,?\[([^]]+)\])+
\])
```

Sorry for changing the question in the middle, I tried to simplify the input for the question, and [some solution below (Avinash Raj)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26233622/587467) does solve the prior input, but not this one...

## Edit 2:

I seemed to overly simplified my question, for the sake of readability... this is my actual and full requirement:

[How to get repeating groups that nest within another group with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234495/how-to-get-repeating-groups-that-nest-within-another-group-with-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try this?

```
(?:Something(?:`(\d+))?\[|(?<!^)\G)\[*([^\[\],\s]*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oU4qI3/4)

Comment: Your solution was almost it, but my problem is a bit more complicated - please see my edit...

Comment: so you want to match the strings within `[]` only on the line which contains the `Something number`. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes. And I want to get the number and the leading `Something` too, but both the number and the `[]` group can be missing, so it's all inside a group (to allow me to make it conditional: it can be `Something'2[[One],[Two]]` or just `Something` for instance, so I want to place it all inside conditional non-capturing group: `(?:...)?`

Comment: see here http://regex101.com/r/oU4qI3/3 . Get the count from group 1 and the chars inside `[]` from group 2. Group 2 may contain empty strings. Just strip it out. Ideone > http://ideone.com/FL8C9j

Comment: It seems I asked the wrong question :-( your answer is the best, but I tried to simplify things for the question, and it ruined its meaning... so I asked another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234495/how-to-get-repeating-groups-that-nest-within-another-group-with-regex

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about using regex, when you can do it natively.

```
var str = "[[typeOne],[typeTwo],[typeThree]]";
var arr = str.Replace("[","").Replace("]","").Split(','); // easy-peasy
```

[**DEMO**](http://csharppad.com/gist/8d6ef3c155f2a2a38aab)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `\w+` : it matches all elements in the list between brackets. Just add parenthesises if you need to capture: `(\w+)`

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*?(\d+)|^.*?\[|\]$|\[(\w+)\]
```

You can try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/37