# How to get repeating groups that nest within another group with regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have these examplary type strings:

```
"System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"

"System.Collections.IEnumerable"

"System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Type, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"

"Whatever`3[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[ImaginaryType],[System.Type, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"
```

Using regex, I want to extract the main-type, its generic types count, and all the generic types themselves, so for the four examples above, I "catch" these elements correspondingly:

```
"System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable"
    1
    "System.String"

"System.Collections.IEnumerable"
    0

"System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary"
    2
    "System.Int32"
    "System.Type"

"Whatever"
    3
    "System.Int32"
    "ImaginaryType"
    "System.Type"
```

Is there a regex that can do that?

Comment: Yes. You can use nested groups, like so: `^(first-group-expression (second-group-expression))$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with this pattern:

```
string pattern = @"
(?:   # two possible entry points
    \G(?!\A)       # contigous to the precedent match
  |                # OR
    \A             # at the start of the string
    (?<main> [^`]+ )  ` (?<number> [0-9]+ ) \[
)

\[ (?<type> [^],]+ ) # generic type
[^]]* ]              # all until the next closing square bracket
(?: , | ]\z )

| \A (?<main> [^`]+ ) # or a main-type without generic types
";

RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace;

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options)) { ...
```

If you project to use the pattern several times, it's better to compile it once and for all.
Note that you can reduce the regex engine work using this variant instead:

```
string pattern = @"
  \G(?!\A) \[
  (?<type> [^],]+ )
  [^]]* ] (?: , | ]\z )
|
  \A
  (?<main> [^`]+ ) 
  (?:
      ` (?<number> [0-9]+ )
      \[{2}
      (?<type> [^],]+ )
      [^]]* ]
      (?: , | ]\z )
    |
      \z
  )";
```

If you want to ensure that the end of the string has been reached you can replace `]\z` with `(?<endcheck>]\z)` and control if the group exist in the last match.

Comment: Wow! great answer :-) but it still misses with the last example: `"Whatever'3[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[ImaginaryType],[System.Type, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"` - (changed the back-tick with apostrophe, due to SO's parsing) it stops at the second type - the `ImaginaryType`, since it doesn't precede any comma...

Comment: Argh, I've been sweating on this for some time and this Dynamic Duo knocks it out of the park. Trying to catch the third case of Tal :)

Comment: @Tal: you only need to add the closing square bracket in the negated character class, see my edit.